# How to remove a loaded class from classloader?

Tags: java

My situation is like this - two test cases, let's say TestA and TestB need to run in different env. However TestA goes first, it will dynamically compile some generated codes, add them in classpath and then load them. On the contrary, TestB need a clean env which does not include previously loaded classes. 
Is there anyway to do that? Clean up classloader, remove specific loaded class?